# Looking for geo-taxonomies libraries

Tags: geolocation

Can I create a geo-taxonomy map by using all tags and locations of Flickr?

Otherwise, is there any geo-taxonomy library I can use for my experiments describing world (or smaller areas) with tags?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think Google Maps geolocation API is what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you sure ? What I need is to get tags given a geographic location (or area). Let's say, I zoom in a country and I see on the maps tags related to the pictures taken in that country, or at least tags somehow related to that specific area.

Comment: I don't necessarily need to see them on the map, also a list of returned tags given a location is fine.

Comment: @Patrick, Try google geoencoding api, http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: Thanks, however I don't think it can help. I need semantic tags.. for example if I select a stadium or arena, I should see "concert, football match" etc.